# Explanation of visudo lock file

Tags: lock, visudo

When I edit /etc/sudoers using visudo, I think it saves to sudoers.tmp, checks it for errors, then copies it to the real `/etc/sudoers`.

However, I can't confirm my theory (how the lock file is used) in the man pages:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/visudo.8.html - it's not described there.

Does anyone know if this behavior is described anywhere? Or is this because lock files are so common it's not described in visudo?

Comment: it *is* in the manpages: FILES

       ` /etc/sudoers `          List of who can run what
       `/etc/sudoers.tmp `      Lock file for visudo

Comment: What I meant is: how the lock file is used, and what it does is not explained.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I don't see a description. Your assumption is correct however: if you run `sudo visudo` look at the top line; it sais you are editing `/etc/sudoers.tmp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mentioned in `man visudo`.

From `man visudo` go to `FILES` section, you will find :

> ```
>  /etc/sudoers.tmp          Lock file for visudo
> ```

It is also described in the illustration of `-f` option :

> -f sudoers, --file=sudoers
>
> Specify an alternate sudoers file location.  With this option, 
>   visudo will edit (or check) the sudoers file of your
>   choice,
>                    instead of the default, /etc/sudoers.  The lock file used is the specified sudoers file with “.tmp” appended to it.  In
>                    check-only mode only, the argument to -f may be ‘-’, indicating that sudoers will be read from the standard input.

If you are interested you can trace the system calls, here what you will find :

```
open("/etc/sudoers.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0600) = 7
```

**EDIT :**

Your concept is right and yes i also personally think that as this is a generic concept it is not mentioned in the man page.

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind taking a look at my clarification of the question below the question? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Tosh check my edits